# Inheritance in XNA Game-- Base class first or later

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna

I am new to XNA 4.0 Game programming, I want to ask if I have class A inherit class B, for example.

In the override Update method, the override Draw method and other override methods in class A

Should I call base.Update, base.Draw and base.other override methods 
before or after doing the process for A (the subclass)?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It all depends on the logic you have in your base and the logic you need to implement in the derived class. This is pretty open ended.

Comment: Like the other guys mentioned, it all comes down to preferences, as well as what works in your game. Sometimes you might want to change a position before updating it, and in other situations you might way want to grab input after it has been updated from a base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the situation.

If your overriding methods that raise events (method names that begin with "On"), typically you would do sub class processing first and then call the base member to raise the event.

In other cases you may call the base member first, or not even call the base class member at all.

There's no universal answer. Establish a pattern and stick with it.